# My image won't load into pygame, even though I have the files in the same directory as the game

Tags: python, image, file, directory, pygame

All my files are in the same directory Documents/Coding/My Python Scripts/Doomsday/Doomsday
(I know I have a folder that is named Doomsday inside a folder named Doomsday)
If anyone could help that would be great,
LMK if you need anymore details!
FILLER FILLER FILLER FILLER FILLER FILLER
FILLER FILLER FILLER FILLER FILLER FILLER
FILLER FILLER FILLER FILLER FILLER FILLER
FILLER FILLER FILLER FILLER FILLER FILLER

```
import pygame



#intialize the pygame
pygame.init()

#Screen 
Screenwid=500
Screenh=500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((Screenwid, Screenh))

#Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption('Doomsday: Out Of Time')

#Dimisions of Rectangle
height=64
width=64
x = 50
y= 450
vel=5

#Jumping 

isJump= False
jumpCount=10

#Character Animation
left=False
right=False
walkCount=0

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('char2.1.1.jpg'), pygame.image.load('char2.1.2.jpg'), pygame.image.load('char2.1.3.jpg'), 
            pygame.image.load('char2.2.1.jpg'), pygame.image.load('char2.2.2.jpg'), pygame.image.load('char2.2.3.jpg'), 
            pygame.image.load('char2.3.1.jpg'), pygame.image.load('char2.3.2.jpg'), pygame.image.load('char2.3.3.jpg')]

walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('char3.1.1.jpg'), pygame.image.load('char3.1.2.jpg'), pygame.image.load('char3.1.3.jpg'),
            pygame.image.load('char3.2.1.jpg'), pygame.image.load('char3.2.2.jpg'), pygame.image.load('char3.2.3.jpg'), 
            pygame.image.load('char3.3.1.jpg'), pygame.image.load('char3.3.2.jpg'), pygame.image.load('char3.3.3.jpg')]
bg = pygame.image.load('cityimage.png')
char = pygame.image.load('char1.1.1.jpg')

def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    win.blit((bg,(0,0)))
    
    #If we didn't cap the walkCount at 27, we would run out of images, or frames 9 images x 3 frames = 27
    if walkCount +1 >= 27:
        walkCount=0

    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3],(x,y))
        walkCount+=1

    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3],(x,y))
        walkCount +=1

    else:
        win.blit(char, (x,y))

    pygame.display.update()

#Frame Rate
clcok= pygame.time.Clock()

#Game Loop
run=True
while run:
    Clock.tick(27)
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    #Color Background
    win.fill((255,0,0))
    #Background Image
    #screen.blit(bkgd,(0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run=False

    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
        left= True
        right=False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < Screenwid - width- vel:
        x += vel
        left=False
        right=True
    else:
        right=False
        left=False
        walkCount=0
    if not(isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump=True
            left=False
            right=False
            walkcount=0 
    else:
        #If the jump is at its orginal state
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            #neg makes it go down after the Apex
            if jumpCount < 0:
                #When the jump is at its Apex, neg impacts the Jump Count by making it go down
                neg= -1
            #The y is decreased so the character goes up, increases 100p,90p, going down by 10.
            y -= jumpCount ** 2 * 0.5 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1

        else:
            isJump= False
            jumpCount=10
            
    redrawGameWindow()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Can you show me your whole code?

Comment: I added the whole code to the post now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
clcok= pygame.time.Clock()
```

into

```
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

and

```
win.blit((bg,(0,0)))
```

into

```
win.blit(bg,(0,0))
```